# GSound (libcanberra) can only play phone-incoming-call

Tags: python-3.x, gtk

This simple example below works, and plays the incoming phone call system sound (from freedesktop /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo):

```
import gi
gi.require_version('GSound', '1.0')
from gi.repository import GLib, GSound

ctx = GSound.Context()
ctx.init()
ctx.play_simple({GSound.ATTR_EVENT_ID: "phone-incoming-call"})
GLib.usleep(2000000)
```

But I have other system sounds installed, and none of the others work. If I use the id "complete" or "message", for example, the script doesn't throw any errors, and acts as though it's working, but there is no sound at all. In contrast, if I enter some non-existent id "blah", play_simple() throws an exception that the audio file isn't found (which tells me that the other sound files must be loading just fine).

Do other people have the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer in the GSound documentation:

> GSound.ATTR_CANBERRA_VOLUME= 'canberra.volume'
>
> A special attribute that can be used to control the volume this sound event is played in if the backend supports it. A floating point value for the decibel multiplier for the sound. 0 dB relates to zero gain, and is the default volume these sounds are played in.
>
> If the list of attributes is handed on to the sound server this attribute is stripped from it.

So the problem is that I have to set the volume in dB with the GSound.ATTR_CANBERRA_VOLUME attribute, otherwise the sound is played at 0dB by default (which is inaudible).

Working example:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('GSound', '1.0')
from gi.repository import GLib, GSound

ctx = GSound.Context()
ctx.init()
ctx.play_simple({GSound.ATTR_EVENT_ID: "complete",
                 GSound.ATTR_CANBERRA_VOLUME: "1"})
GLib.usleep(2000000)
```

Comment: Seems to me a default volume of 0 is pretty dumb.

Comment: Why? Zero gain means unaltered loudness